# Problem with Migration from NUnit 2.6.0 to 3.11.0

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

During migration from Nunit 2.6.0 to 3.11.0, in 2.6 RandomAttribute Class has method public override IEnumerable GetData(ParameterInfo param), in 3.11.0 it's been changed to public IEnumerable GetData(IParameterInfo param).we override GetData in 2.6 what is the alternative to do the same in 3.11.0?

Comment: If they had a breaking change in new version you'll have to update your code.

Comment: Depends on what you are doing in the override. You'll need to supply some more info in order to get a good answer. The GetData method defines what a data attribute does so, in principle, you could be making it do virtually anything, even returning a constant!

Comment: public override IEnumerable GetData(ParameterInfo parameter)
        {
            if (!scanTypes.Contains(ModelParams.Scanner))
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<int>();
            }
            if (scanModels == null)
            {
                return base.GetData(parameter);
            }
            return scanModels.Contains(ModelParams.Model) ? base.GetData(parameter) : Enumerable.Empty<int>();
        }  This what i am doing inside GetData() function

Comment: @Charlie Is there a way solve above issue

Comment: It's best to edit your question if you have new information to add. In particular, code doesn't come across really well in a comment. Where does scanModels come from?